# how to fix install kde on ubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I want to install kde on ubuntu. I type `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`. But I have a error like this:

[image]

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a fresh install and don't have any data on that machine that you want to keep, then I would look into installing Kubuntu, which is a distribution of Ubuntu, but with the KDE desktop already installed with all of it's dependencies, instead of the Gnome desktop that comes native with the standard Ubuntu distributions. http://kubuntu.org/

I ran into a similar issue a while back, and it was because I needed to install certain dependencies for that desktop. For more information about Linux desktops: http://linuxreviews.org/software/desktops/

Comment: The standard distributions come with Unity, and not with Gnome.

Comment: Doesn't it? "Unity is a graphical shell for the GNOME desktop environment developed by Canonical Ltd. for its Ubuntu operating system."